# Fill between rows based on rows on first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, fill, vba

I have a data that looks like this

[image]

I would like to have a formula/vba that makes it like this

[image]

Any ideas?

I am very new in Excel

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either manually or with *VBA*.  Say we have:

[image]

Running this short macro:

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each rr In r
        rr.FillDown
    Next
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

**Note:**

1. there is no error checking - you will see an error if there are no empties to be filled
2. the empties must be true empties, not formulas returning a null
3. the fill is for the first column only, you must modify it to handle other columns.

Answer (score 0):

One possible manual way:
Assuming "name1" is in cell A2, you can input =$A$2 in cell A3 (e.g. first empty cell below "name1") and copy to all empty cells above "name2".

The $ sign will lock the reference to the selected cell. You can input the $ manually or press F4 after selecting the cell you are referencing.